# Regularity for weak Solution

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm studying the multi-dimensional variation problem in this form
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u +u = f,&\text{on }\Omega,\\ 
u = 0,&\text{on }\partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
I know that if $f$ belongs to $L^2(\Omega)$ then $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, but when I study the regularity of the weak solution, it is also true that if $f\in H^1$ then $u\in H^3$: I don't know how to prove this result (assuming that $\Omega$ is a smooth domain).

Answer (score 4):

For the interior estimates away from the boundary what you ask basically follows from taking partial derivatives of the PDE and using $f\in L^2(\Omega) \implies u \in H^2(\Omega)$. Assume $f\in H^1(\Omega)$, in particular $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and hence $u\in H^2(\Omega)$. Then $ \nabla u \in H^1(\Omega) $ (but has not Dirichlet boundary condition) and taking the partial derivatives in the weak formulation it weakly solves $-\Delta(\nabla u) +\nabla u =\nabla f$ in every $\Omega' \subset \subset \Omega$. Then $\nabla f\in L^2(\Omega) \implies \nabla u \in H^2_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$ and hence $u\in H^3_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$.